# Delete and Insert from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little bit confused why it does not work.

What i want  is that control db if for ex 2012-02-21 exist in DB delete it and insert again  but it does not work why

my full code is that but else statement doesnt work :S

```
 $ga->requestAccountData();
$mysql = new mysql();
$mysql->connect();



    // $startDate = date("Y-m-d");
    $startDate = "2012-02-21";

     $dbResult = mysql_query("select * from profiles where profile_Date='".$startDate."'");
     $query =  mysql_num_rows($dbResult);
     if($query > 0)
     {

         mysql_query("delete from profiles where profile_Date='".$startDate."'");
         foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {


        $ga->requestReportData($result->getProfileId(),array('eventCategory','eventAction'),array('totalEvents'),$sort_metric=null,$filter='eventAction==InitPlayer',$start_date=$startDate,$end_date=$startDate);
        foreach($ga->getResults() as $result2)
        {
            echo $result;
            echo $result2->geteventCategory()."<br />";
            echo $result2->geteventAction();
            echo $result2->gettotalEvents();
            "<br />";
            "<br />";
            "<br />";

              $mysql->query("insert into profiles values(" . $result->getProfileId() . ",'" . $result . "','".$result2->geteventCategory()."','".$result2->geteventAction()."','".$result2->gettotalEvents()."','".$startDate."')");

         }
        }
     }
     else
     {
         foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {


        $ga->requestReportData($result->getProfileId(),array('eventCategory','eventAction'),array('totalEvents'),$sort_metric=null,$filter='eventAction==InitPlayer',$start_date=$startDate,$end_date=$startDate);
        foreach($ga->getResults() as $result2)
        {
            echo $result;
            echo $result2->geteventCategory()."<br />";
            echo $result2->geteventAction();
            echo $result2->gettotalEvents();
            "<br />";
            "<br />";
            "<br />";

              $mysql->query("insert into profiles values(" . $result->getProfileId() . ",'" . $result . "','".$result2->geteventCategory()."','".$result2->geteventAction()."','".$result2->gettotalEvents()."','".$startDate."')");

         }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to first delete and then insert? you can use update query as well. Also what is the data type of the field profile_Date ? Is it set date or date and time?

Comment: the data count sometimes change so i first delete then insert . profile date is varchar.

Comment: @MertMETİN I think you are facing the issue that you can delete the profiles but could not able to insert in. For this one possible reason is you must store the data ($ga->getResults()) in array and then use it before deleting the records.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `mysql_num_rows` to count the results selected and not `mysql_affected_rows` which applies to queries altering data (insert, update, delete etc.)

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from profiles where profile_Date='".$startDate."'");
$count =  mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0) { 
   ... 
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's `REPLACE` functionality ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html)).
It basically works like `INSERT`, with the exception that if a value with the same key already exists in the database, at first the existing value will be removed and afterwards the new value will be inserted as completely new entry. If there is no existing value, it will behave like `INSERT`.

#### Watch out for the differences to `UPDATE`

The difference to `UPDATE` is hidden in the details:

- since an existing value will actually be removed, all referenced foreign keys constraints will be removed too.
- `UPDATE` will just update the values provided, with `INSERT` the other columns will get the default value (practical example: a field name `timestamp_created` with the default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will be unchanged in an `UPDATE` statement, but will display the current time in a `REPLACE` statement)